# How do I remove packages that apt is going to install?

Tags: apt, package-management

I tried to install Java 9, but this version was removed from Oracle servers and cannot be downloaded by `apt`. Now whenever I run apt to upgrade my system, apt is complaining about not being able to download Java 9. How do I fix this behaviour? I don't want to install Java 9 and don't want to see that annoying message of apt.

When I run 'apt autoremove' I got (truncated output):

....

```
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22+linuxmint1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up oracle-java9-installer (9.0.4-1) ...
No /var/cache/oracle-jdk9-installer/wgetrc file found.
Creating /var/cache/oracle-jdk9-installer/wgetrc and
using default oracle-java9-installer wgetrc settings for it.
Downloading Oracle Java 9...
```

`$ apt-cache policy oracle-java9-installer`

```
oracle-java9-installer:
  Installed: 9.0.4-1
  Candidate: 9.0.4-1
  Version table:
 *** 9.0.4-1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/java/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: What's the exact error message you get? Maybe removing Java 9 from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`?

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy oracle-java9-installer` to the question.

Comment: @user535733 It did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: @user535733 do post an answer.

Comment: @muru added answer

Answer (score 2):

Apt's list of packages includes a notation of whether a package should be installed (*install*) or not (*remove*).

This notation is persistent: If a package is marked *install*, apt will keep trying to install the package until apt succeeds.

Use the `apt-mark` command to change the list entry.
In this case, try `sudo apt-mark remove oracle-java9-installer`